# hide/remove table row within ajax call from button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide a row within a html table after clicking on a button in the same row.

A simplified version looks like this:

[image]

the table gets populated after a successful ajax call.

triggering the function `deleteFilterFromTable(id, user_id)` triggers another ajax call, which deletes the filter from the list in the database. the call itself works.

To make it easier for the user I'd like to hide the row which contains the button the user clicked on to give some sort of optical feedback. I tried adding the CSS class `hidden` to the parent element, or simply use `.hide()` on the closest `tr` onclick. Any idea why this does not hide the row?

thank you very much in advance!

**html**

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="filter_table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col">Filter</th>
         <th scope="col" width="70px">Aktion</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>LOL9999</td>
         <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-rounded pt-2 pb-2" onclick="deleteFilterFromTable(22, 495)"><i class="mdi mdi-delete-forever mx-2"></i></button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Testinger</td>
         <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-rounded pt-2 pb-2" onclick="deleteFilterFromTable(1, 495)"><i class="mdi mdi-delete-forever mx-2"></i></button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>V-00019</td>
         <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-rounded pt-2 pb-2" onclick="deleteFilterFromTable(2, 495)"><i class="mdi mdi-delete-forever mx-2"></i></button></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**jquery**

```
function deleteFilterFromTable(filter_id, filter_uid){
    $.ajax({
        url: `/backend/DeleteFilterByFilterId?filter_id=${filter_id}&uid=${filter_uid}`,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response){ 
            $(this).closest('tr').hide();
        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: $(this).parent().parent().remove();

Does this work?

Comment: Hi @Timberman, unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: Hi, pass `this` here `onclick="deleteFilterFromTable(22, 495 ,this)"` as well then change function like this -> `function deleteFilterFromTable(filter_id, filter_uid ,el){` lastly use `$(el)..` instead of `$(this)..` inside ajax call.

Comment: Thank you guys! this did the trick!

Comment: If the answer helped, please mark it as a solution. You'll help others who come to this post with the same problem they're having.

Comment: sorry, was unable to do so yesterday due to the 5 minutes mark. marked it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your onclick to:

```
onclick="deleteFilterFromTable(2, 495, this)"
```

and the function to this

```
function deleteFilterFromTable(filter_id, filter_uid, element){
    $.ajax({
        url: `/backend/DeleteFilterByFilterId?filter_id=${filter_id}&uid=${filter_uid}`,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response){ 
            $(element).closest('tr').hide();
        } 
    });
}
```

$(this) was not pointing to the element, you are now adding the element to one of the arguments.

Comment: additionally , this could also beneficiate not to be put inline and with the data being a data-attribute of the button...